# Enable mod_deflate

Tags: apache

I am trying to enable mod_deflate. I have Apache 2.0+ and tried this code in my .htaccess file:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

It did not compress any of my files when I tested my site in firebug. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

I used this and it worked. It was an internet history problem. My yahoo Yslow was saving the results from the first check so when I modified the htaccess the difference did not show up.

Answer (score 1):

As this'll be moved to SF soon, Shouldn't it be:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
```

Otherwise the regex becomes `\.js`, for example (because you've escaped the '\').

Comment: that works but it ignores all my js and css files for some reason. I only save 10kb :(

Comment: What happens if you add `text/javascript` to the AddOutputFilterByType` line? Does that help?

Comment: unfortunately not lol, it only compresses my php file, it does not compress js or css. Could this be because they are below the root directory?